# Accordion will not show all the text

Tags: html, accordion

I've recently been putting text into an accordion and making it look "nicer" in my opinion, but I realised on the second tab "DarkRP rules" it will not show all the text, it cuts off the rest.

[image]

Under the "•" There should be more text..
Also, another thing, is I'd like to make the "

This means you dont return to the point of death for 5 minutes and forget your past life.

" move over to the right, so it's under the text "(New life rule)"

Any help will be awesome and appreciated :)

```css
* {
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body { font-family: 'Lato'; }

h1 {
  font-size: 2em;
  padding: 2em;
  text-align: center;
}

.accordion dl { border: 3px solid #333; }

.accordion dl:after {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  height: 1em;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #007dff;
}

.accordion dt > a {
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: 700;
  padding: 2em;
  display: block;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #eee;
  -webkit-transition: background-color 0.5s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: background-color 0.5s ease-in-out;
  transition: background-color 0.5s ease-in-out;
}

.accordion dd {
  background-color: #eee;
  font-size: 1em;
  line-height: 1.5em;
}

.accordion dd > p {
  padding: 1em 2em 1em 2em;
  margin: 0;
}

.accordion {
  position: relative;
  background-color: #eee;
}

.container {
  max-width: 960px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 2em 0 2em 0;
}

.accordionTitle {
  background-color: #666666; 
  border-bottom: 2px solid #007dff;
}

.accordionTitle:before {
  content: "+";
  font-size: 1.5em;
  line-height: 0.5em;
  float: left;
  -moz-transition: -moz-transform 0.3s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: -o-transform 0.3s ease-in-out;
  -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 0.3s ease-in-out;
  transition: transform 0.3s ease-in-out;
}

.accordionTitle:hover { background-color: #333; }

.accordionTitleActive { background-color: #333; }

.accordionTitleActive:before {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-225deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(-225deg);
  transform: rotate(-225deg);
}

.accordionItem {
  height: auto;
  overflow: hidden;
}
@media all {

.accordionItem {
  max-height: 50em;
  -moz-transition: max-height 1s;
  -o-transition: max-height 1s;
  -webkit-transition: max-height 1s;
  transition: max-height 1s;
}
}
@media screen and (min-width: 48em) {

.accordionItem {
  max-height: 15em;
  -moz-transition: max-height 0.5s;
  -o-transition: max-height 0.5s;
  -webkit-transition: max-height 0.5s;
  transition: max-height 0.5s;
}
}

.accordionItemCollapsed { max-height: 0; }

.animateIn {
  -webkit-animation-name: accordionIn;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 0.65s;
  -webkit-animation-iteration-count: 1;
  -webkit-animation-direction: normal;
  -webkit-animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
  -webkit-animation-fill-mode: both;
  -webkit-animation-delay: 0s;
  -moz-animation-name: normal;
  -moz-animation-duration: 0.65s;
  -moz-animation-iteration-count: 1;
  -moz-animation-direction: alternate;
  -moz-animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
  -moz-animation-fill-mode: both;
  -moz-animation-delay: 0s;
  animation-name: accordionIn;
  animation-duration: 0.65s;
  animation-iteration-count: 1;
  animation-direction: normal;
  animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
  animation-fill-mode: both;
  animation-delay: 0s;
}

.animateOut {
  -webkit-animation-name: accordionOut;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 0.75s;
  -webkit-animation-iteration-count: 1;
  -webkit-animation-direction: alternate;
  -webkit-animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
  -webkit-animation-fill-mode: both;
  -webkit-animation-delay: 0s;
  -moz-animation-name: accordionOut;
  -moz-animation-duration: 0.75s;
  -moz-animation-iteration-count: 1;
  -moz-animation-direction: alternate;
  -moz-animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
  -moz-animation-fill-mode: both;
  -moz-animation-delay: 0s;
  animation-name: accordionOut;
  animation-duration: 0.75s;
  animation-iteration-count: 1;
  animation-direction: alternate;
  animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
  animation-fill-mode: both;
  animation-delay: 0s;
}
 @-webkit-keyframes 
accordionIn {  0% {
 opacity: 0;
 -webkit-transform: scale(0.8);
}
 100% {
 opacity: 1;
 -webkit-transform: scale(1);
}
}
@-moz-keyframes 
accordionIn {  0% {
 opacity: 0;
 -moz-transform: scale(0.8);
}
 100% {
 opacity: 1;
 -moz-transform: scale(1);
}
}
@keyframes 
accordionIn {  0% {
 opacity: 0;
 transform: scale(0.8);
}
 100% {
 opacity: 1;
 transform: scale(1);
}
}
@-webkit-keyframes 
accordionOut {  0% {
 opacity: 1;
 -webkit-transform: scale(1);
}
 100% {
 opacity: 0;
 -webkit-transform: scale(0.8);
}
}
@-moz-keyframes 
accordionOut {  0% {
 opacity: 1;
 -moz-transform: scale(1);
}
 100% {
 opacity: 0;
 -moz-transform: scale(0.8);
}
}
@keyframes 
accordionOut {  0% {
 opacity: 1;
 transform: scale(1);
}
 100% {
 opacity: 0;
 transform: scale(0.8);
}
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <h1>Hydroxal DarkRP Rules</h1>
  <div class="css-script-ads" align="center"><script type="text/javascript"><!--
</script> 
      <script type="text/javascript"
src="//pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/show_ads.js">
</script></div>
  <div class="accordion">
    <dl>
      <dt><a class="accordionTitle" href="#">Basic Rules.</a></dt>
      <dd class="accordionItem accordionItemCollapsed">
        <p>Respect everyone. No threats, teasing or trolling.</p>
        <p>There is no bunny hopping. It is unrealistic.</p>
  <p>Body-blocking is highly annoying, don't do it.</p>
  <p>Do not spam things. This includes your flashlight, props, lights, ropes and mic spam.</p>
  <p>Do not impersonate other exsisting members</p>
      </dd>
      <dt><a href="#" class="accordionTitle">DarkRP Rules.</a></dt>
      <dd class="accordionItem accordionItemCollapsed">
        <p>• Follow NLR (New Life Rule)</p>
                            <ul>
                             <p>This means you dont return to the point of death for 5 minutes and forget your past life.</p>
                         </ul>
       <p>•Do not RDM (Random Deathmatch) You must have a valid reason to injure or kill someone.</p>
    <p>• Do not metagame</p>
          <li></li><li></li> <p>Eg. You can not kick the Thief out your store and leave the citizen purely based on the fact that he's a thief. This is metagame</p>
        <p>• Follow your job description.</p>
     <p>• Follow your Job description</p>
     <li></li><li></li> <p>Eg. If your job description says "You must sell weapons to public," then do so.</p>
       
  
      </dd>
      <dt><a href="#" class="accordionTitle">Other.</a></dt>
      <dd class="accordionItem accordionItemCollapsed">
        <p>Props are for building only.</p>
        <p>Do not abuse fading door.</p>
      
   </dd>
    </dl>
  </div>
</div>
<script>

( function( window ) {

'use strict';



function classReg( className ) {
  return new RegExp("(^|\\s+)" + className + "(\\s+|$)");
}


var hasClass, addClass, removeClass;

if ( 'classList' in document.documentElement ) {
  hasClass = function( elem, c ) {
    return elem.classList.contains( c );
  };
  addClass = function( elem, c ) {
    elem.classList.add( c );
  };
  removeClass = function( elem, c ) {
    elem.classList.remove( c );
  };
}
else {
  hasClass = function( elem, c ) {
    return classReg( c ).test( elem.className );
  };
  addClass = function( elem, c ) {
    if ( !hasClass( elem, c ) ) {
      elem.className = elem.className + ' ' + c;
    }
  };
  removeClass = function( elem, c ) {
    elem.className = elem.className.replace( classReg( c ), ' ' );
  };
}

function toggleClass( elem, c ) {
  var fn = hasClass( elem, c ) ? removeClass : addClass;
  fn( elem, c );
}

var classie = {
  
  hasClass: hasClass,
  addClass: addClass,
  removeClass: removeClass,
  toggleClass: toggleClass,
  
  has: hasClass,
  add: addClass,
  remove: removeClass,
  toggle: toggleClass
};


if ( typeof define === 'function' && define.amd ) {
  
  define( classie );
} else {
  
  window.classie = classie;
}

})( window );


var $ = function(selector){
  return document.querySelector(selector);
}
var accordion = $('.accordion');






accordion.addEventListener("click",function(e) {
  e.stopPropagation();
  e.preventDefault();
  if(e.target && e.target.nodeName == "A") {
    var classes = e.target.className.split(" ");
    if(classes) {
      for(var x = 0; x < classes.length; x++) {
        if(classes[x] == "accordionTitle") {
          var title = e.target;

          
          var content = e.target.parentNode.nextElementSibling;
          
          
         
          classie.toggle(title, 'accordionTitleActive');
          
          if(classie.has(content, 'accordionItemCollapsed')) {
            if(classie.has(content, 'animateOut')){
              classie.remove(content, 'animateOut');
            }
            classie.add(content, 'animateIn');

          }else{
             classie.remove(content, 'animateIn');
             classie.add(content, 'animateOut');
          }
          
          classie.toggle(content, 'accordionItemCollapsed');



          
        }
      }
    }
    
  }
});
</script>
<script>
  (function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
  (i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
  m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
  })(window,document,'script','//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');

  ga('create', 'UA-46156385-1', 'cssscript.com');
  ga('send', 'pageview');

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You have invalid `html`

Comment: You have wrong media query at `@media all {
.accordionItem {
  max-height: 50em;
  -moz-transition: max-height 1s;
  -o-transition: max-height 1s;
  -webkit-transition: max-height 1s;
  transition: max-height 1s;
}
}`.You have set the max-height.

Answer (score 0):

You have a `invalid` html. `li` elements should have a `ul` parent.

You can validate it over here: http://www.freeformatter.com/html-validator.html

Try this:

```js
(function(window) {

  'use strict';



  function classReg(className) {
    return new RegExp("(^|\\s+)" + className + "(\\s+|$)");
  }


  var hasClass, addClass, removeClass;

  if ('classList' in document.documentElement) {
    hasClass = function(elem, c) {
      return elem.classList.contains(c);
    };
    addClass = function(elem, c) {
      elem.classList.add(c);
    };
    removeClass = function(elem, c) {
      elem.classList.remove(c);
    };
  } else {
    hasClass = function(elem, c) {
      return classReg(c).test(elem.className);
    };
    addClass = function(elem, c) {
      if (!hasClass(elem, c)) {
        elem.className = elem.className + ' ' + c;
      }
    };
    removeClass = function(elem, c) {
      elem.className = elem.className.replace(classReg(c), ' ');
    };
  }

  function toggleClass(elem, c) {
    var fn = hasClass(elem, c) ? removeClass : addClass;
    fn(elem, c);
  }

  var classie = {

    hasClass: hasClass,
    addClass: addClass,
    removeClass: removeClass,
    toggleClass: toggleClass,

    has: hasClass,
    add: addClass,
    remove: removeClass,
    toggle: toggleClass
  };


  if (typeof define === 'function' && define.amd) {

    define(classie);
  } else {

    window.classie = classie;
  }

})(window);


var $ = function(selector) {
  return document.querySelector(selector);
}
var accordion = $('.accordion');






accordion.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
  e.stopPropagation();
  e.preventDefault();
  if (e.target && e.target.nodeName == "A") {
    var classes = e.target.className.split(" ");
    if (classes) {
      for (var x = 0; x < classes.length; x++) {
        if (classes[x] == "accordionTitle") {
          var title = e.target;


          var content = e.target.parentNode.nextElementSibling;



          classie.toggle(title, 'accordionTitleActive');

          if (classie.has(content, 'accordionItemCollapsed')) {
            if (classie.has(content, 'animateOut')) {
              classie.remove(content, 'animateOut');
            }
            classie.add(content, 'animateIn');

          } else {
            classie.remove(content, 'animateIn');
            classie.add(content, 'animateOut');
          }

          classie.toggle(content, 'accordionItemCollapsed');




        }
      }
    }

  }
});
```

```css
* {
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
body {
  font-family: 'Lato';
}
h1 {
  font-size: 2em;
  padding: 2em;
  text-align: center;
}
.accordion dl {
  border: 3px solid #333;
}
.accordion dl:after {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  height: 1em;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #007dff;
}
.accordion dt > a {
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: 700;
  padding: 2em;
  display: block;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #eee;
  -webkit-transition: background-color 0.5s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: background-color 0.5s ease-in-out;
  transition: background-color 0.5s ease-in-out;
}
.accordion dd {
  background-color: #eee;
  font-size: 1em;
  line-height: 1.5em;
}
.accordion dd > p {
  padding: 1em 2em 1em 2em;
  margin: 0;
}
.accordion {
  position: relative;
  background-color: #eee;
}
.container {
  max-width: 960px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 2em 0 2em 0;
}
.accordionTitle {
  background-color: #666666;
  border-bottom: 2px solid #007dff;
}
.accordionTitle:before {
  content: "+";
  font-size: 1.5em;
  line-height: 0.5em;
  float: left;
  -moz-transition: -moz-transform 0.3s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: -o-transform 0.3s ease-in-out;
  -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 0.3s ease-in-out;
  transition: transform 0.3s ease-in-out;
}
.accordionTitle:hover {
  background-color: #333;
}
.accordionTitleActive {
  background-color: #333;
}
.accordionTitleActive:before {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-225deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(-225deg);
  transform: rotate(-225deg);
}
.accordionItem {
  height: auto;
  overflow: hidden;
}
@media all {
  .accordionItem {
    max-height: 50em;
    -moz-transition: max-height 1s;
    -o-transition: max-height 1s;
    -webkit-transition: max-height 1s;
    transition: max-height 1s;
  }
}
@media screen and (min-width: 48em) {
  .accordionItem {
    max-height: 15em;
    -moz-transition: max-height 0.5s;
    -o-transition: max-height 0.5s;
    -webkit-transition: max-height 0.5s;
    transition: max-height 0.5s;
  }
}
.accordionItemCollapsed {
  max-height: 0;
}
.animateIn {
  -webkit-animation-name: accordionIn;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 0.65s;
  -webkit-animation-iteration-count: 1;
  -webkit-animation-direction: normal;
  -webkit-animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
  -webkit-animation-fill-mode: both;
  -webkit-animation-delay: 0s;
  -moz-animation-name: normal;
  -moz-animation-duration: 0.65s;
  -moz-animation-iteration-count: 1;
  -moz-animation-direction: alternate;
  -moz-animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
  -moz-animation-fill-mode: both;
  -moz-animation-delay: 0s;
  animation-name: accordionIn;
  animation-duration: 0.65s;
  animation-iteration-count: 1;
  animation-direction: normal;
  animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
  animation-fill-mode: both;
  animation-delay: 0s;
}
.animateOut {
  -webkit-animation-name: accordionOut;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 0.75s;
  -webkit-animation-iteration-count: 1;
  -webkit-animation-direction: alternate;
  -webkit-animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
  -webkit-animation-fill-mode: both;
  -webkit-animation-delay: 0s;
  -moz-animation-name: accordionOut;
  -moz-animation-duration: 0.75s;
  -moz-animation-iteration-count: 1;
  -moz-animation-direction: alternate;
  -moz-animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
  -moz-animation-fill-mode: both;
  -moz-animation-delay: 0s;
  animation-name: accordionOut;
  animation-duration: 0.75s;
  animation-iteration-count: 1;
  animation-direction: alternate;
  animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
  animation-fill-mode: both;
  animation-delay: 0s;
}
@-webkit-keyframes accordionIn {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transform: scale(0.8);
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 1;
    -webkit-transform: scale(1);
  }
}
@-moz-keyframes accordionIn {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
    -moz-transform: scale(0.8);
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 1;
    -moz-transform: scale(1);
  }
}
@keyframes accordionIn {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
    transform: scale(0.8);
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 1;
    transform: scale(1);
  }
}
@-webkit-keyframes accordionOut {
  0% {
    opacity: 1;
    -webkit-transform: scale(1);
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transform: scale(0.8);
  }
}
@-moz-keyframes accordionOut {
  0% {
    opacity: 1;
    -moz-transform: scale(1);
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 0;
    -moz-transform: scale(0.8);
  }
}
@keyframes accordionOut {
  0% {
    opacity: 1;
    transform: scale(1);
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 0;
    transform: scale(0.8);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <h1>Hydroxal DarkRP Rules</h1>
  <div class="accordion">
    <dl>
      <dt><a class="accordionTitle" href="#">Basic Rules.</a></dt>
      <dd class="accordionItem accordionItemCollapsed">
        <p>Respect everyone. No threats, teasing or trolling.</p>
        <p>There is no bunny hopping. It is unrealistic.</p>
        <p>Body-blocking is highly annoying, don't do it.</p>
        <p>Do not spam things. This includes your flashlight, props, lights, ropes and mic spam.</p>
        <p>Do not impersonate other exsisting members</p>
      </dd>
      <dt><a href="#" class="accordionTitle">DarkRP Rules.</a></dt>
      <dd class="accordionItem accordionItemCollapsed">
        <p>• Follow NLR (New Life Rule)</p>
        <ul>
          <li>This means you dont return to the point of death for 5 minutes and forget your past life.</li>
          <li>•Do not RDM (Random Deathmatch) You must have a valid reason to injure or kill someone.</li>
          <li>• Do not metagame</li>
          <li>Eg. You can not kick the Thief out your store and leave the citizen purely based on the fact that he's a thief. This is metagame</li>
          <li>• Follow your job description.</li>
          <li>• Follow your Job description</li>
          <li>Eg. If your job description says "You must sell weapons to public," then do so.</li>
        </ul>
      </dd>
      <dt><a href="#" class="accordionTitle">Other.</a></dt>
      <dd class="accordionItem accordionItemCollapsed">
        <p>Props are for building only.</p>
        <p>Do not abuse fading door.</p>
      </dd>
    </dl>
  </div>
</div>
```